# Hybris - Backoffice Commerce Search mode

Tags: solr, sap-commerce-cloud, commerce, backoffice

We do have `solr.impex` file defined within our storefront. But backoffice commerce search mode gives blank screen as shown below. What **OOTB** files/extensions I need to set up to see store specific catalogs, facets, results, etc., in the backoffice.

[image]

**Hybris version: 1808**

Comment: Have you tried selecting your store and catalog from the right side of the screen ? Right now, as  it can be seen, there is no navigation Context

Comment: store, catalog and language dropdowns are empty. not sure how to set them up. Not sure how to create navigation context. is it not set/created ootb?

Comment: Try 1. Press F4 and select `Rest Everything` option from the top right corner dropdown  2. Index backoffice config from facet search configurations

Comment: F4 and `Reset Everything` didn't help. But for your suggestion#2, I didn't have any backoffice config within Facet Search Configurations. That could be a problem, i think. What is the best way to bring over `backoffice` index config?